# How can I make a center submenu that is wider than its parent li?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with trying to recreate this submenu in html/css.  The submenu is <s>bigger</s> **wider** than the parent `<li>` which seems to be the main issue.  I need the submenu to be larger than the parent `<li>` and centered on it.  This is what I am trying to recreate:
[image]

---

### Screenshot of current progress:

[image]

So you can see in my version, the width of the submenu `<ul>` is only as big as the parent `<li>`. I need the submenu to be larger than the parent `<li>` and centered on it.

```css
.navbar {
    width: 100%;    
    height:80px;    
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #111111;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    float: left;
    line-height:80px;
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    line-height:80px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:0.8em;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li a {
    position: relative;
}

.nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -20px auto 0;
  }

.nav > li > ul {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}

.flLeft {
    float: left;
}

.flRight {
    float: right;
}

.white {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.darkOrange {
    color: #BF3600;
}

.black {
    color: #111111;
}

.orange {
    color: #FF6200;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav li a:link, .nav li a:visited {
    color: #111111;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FF6200;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">     
        <div class="logo">
            <span class="black">YOUR</span><span class="orange">LOGO</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">TITLE 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TITLE 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>SUBMENU 1</li>
                    <li>SUBMENU 2</li>
                    <li>SUBMENU 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TITLE 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TITLE 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TITLE 5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TITLE 6</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TITLE 7</a>
            </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I've created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gsmzhptu/embedded/result/

Updated fiddle with wide submenu, but not centered below main li menu item: https://jsfiddle.net/gsmzhptu/1/embedded/result/

Comment: You are missing a closing /ul on the parent

Comment: And why not change your ul width from `width: inherit` to say `width: 200px;`?

Comment: Can you make it a little more clear what exactly your expected result is

Comment: https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/RyPyLp?editors=1100

Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: @cale_b I've tried that.  I added a second fiddle showing my results.  It is not centered below the main menu item like in the screnshot.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I want that submenu to be like 50% wider and centered, just like in the original screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I increased the line height. Do you want something like this?

```css
.nav li ul li {
  line-height: 2;
}
```

Check this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gsmzhptu/11/

Comment: It's close, but it's still not centered on the parent `<li>` like in the original screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

### **Positioning Solution**

> `margin: -20px;` and `padding: adjustable 20px;`
>
> `margin-left right` and `padding- left right` should be **exact** and **opposite** to each other.

```
.nav > li > ul{
    margin:-20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.nav li ul li {
{
    margin:10px 0;
}
```

```css
  .navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #111111;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  float: left;
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li a {
  position: relative;
}

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav>li>ul {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav li ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.flLeft {
  float: left;
}

.flRight {
  float: right;
}

.white {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.darkOrange {
  color: #BF3600;
}

.black {
  color: #111111;
}

.orange {
  color: #FF6200;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav li a:link,
.nav li a:visited {
  color: #111111;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #FF6200;
  font-weight: bold;
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="black">YOUR</span><span class="orange">LOGO</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">TITLE 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">TITLE 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li>SUBMENU 1</li>
          <li>SUBMENU 2</li>
          <li>SUBMENU 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">TITLE 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">TITLE 4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">TITLE 5</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">TITLE 6</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">TITLE 7</a>
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```